# Is it possible to use the C API of lua in embedded systems?

Tags: c, lua, embedded, microcontroller

I'm trying to add some lua scripts to a firmware project writen in C. For now, the script is a config table, from which I'm trying to get the value of the `num` variable, all of this using the C API in the `main.c` file.

I'm testing this code including the standard source files of Lua for Desktop in my project (I have read about *eLua*, but the I don't need to implement the full code in Lua, I need to have Lua and C files coexisting in my project).

It works fine when I test this in the computer with the gcc compiler, but when I try to pass the same idea to my microcontroller with the cross compiler it compiles and there are no erros, but it seems to have problems getting the value from the lua file, because the variable `valueFromLua` always equals to 1.

My project folder tree has the following structure:

- Source

  - main.c
- Tools

  - lua

    - scripts

      - config_table.lua

**config_table.lua**

```lua
config_table = {
    num = 10
}
```

**main.c**

```c
  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    uint8_t valueFromLua;

    if(luaL_dofile(L, "./Tools/lua/scripts/config_table.lua") == LUA_OK)
    {
        lua_getglobal(L, "config_table");
        if(lua_istable(L, -1))
        {
            lua_getfield(L, -1, "num");
            valueFromLua = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        valueFromLua = 1;
    }
```

I would appreciate your comments, thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is meaningless without a part number. On an ATtiny2313? No.  On a powerful ARM part?  Probably yes.  Do you know how much of a gulf is in the term "embedded systems?"

Comment: Sorry, I'm using an ARM, specifically an STM32F407VG

Comment: Have you tried to use an absolute path?

Comment: There are at least two `if` conditions. Did you try to find out whether they evaluate to `true`?